# Tell compiler not to execute destructor on my __thread variable

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I specifically want no constructors and no destructors on one of my variables. It's defined as this

```
struct Dummy { ~Dummy() { assert(0); } };
__thread Dummy dumb;
```

The real code is zero initialized and grabs memory out of the thread local memory pool. The pool is destroyed at the end of main so this destructor tries to access a freed memory pool.

I can work around the problem but I wanted to do this in a clean way. 1) Can I tell the compiler to free my pool after all thread local (or global) variables? Or have it initialized before all thread local functions so it's cleaned up at the proper time? Or better yet 2) Not execute the cleanup at all? I could have sworn `__thread` doesn't allow constructors/destructors so I was surprised this even ran.

The stack trace shows `__run_exit_handlers` being the function that calls the destructor. It parents are `exit`,  `__libc_start_main` and `start`. This occurs on both clang and gcc

Comment: Btw, why are you using `__thread` instead of `thread_local`? What does C have to do with this? This isn't C.

Comment: What is C/C++ language? I never heard about it.

Comment: Guys its C++ code using a C extension which both compilers support. Its not hard to understand. If there's a solution that works with thread_local just write an answer with that

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was expecting C like behavior of no constructor/destructor but ok I deleted the tag

Comment: But why are you using C extension in C++?

Comment: ... and it's an old extension too. Both C11 and C++11 supports `thread_local`

Comment: @KamilCuk like I said, because I wanted it to never run a constructor or destructor which sadly doesn't work. I could swear it use to either not compile or not execute them

Comment: @TedLyngmo I already said. I wanted it to never run a constructor or destructor which sadly doesn't work. I could swear it use to either not compile or not execute them

Comment: It seems like a very odd requirement. If the thread which created the variable is dead, why should the variable be kept alive?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It shouldnt and thats exactly what I said

Comment: @TedLyngmo I assume it's not even kept alive, memory most likely is returned to OS. There might be other resources leaking, though.

Comment: What exactly do you want to prevent to happen by not calling the destructor? It sounds like a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Aconcagua Can you actually not understand the question? Maybe read what memory pools are

Comment: @EricStotch I must be reading the question all wrong. `thread_local` variables will be destroyed when the thread that created them dies. "_The pool is destroyed at the end of main so this destructor tries to access a freed memory pool_" - You did something wrong implementing the pool or threading. If the threads grab memory from a pool, they surely return it to the pool when they die? Are all threads joined before you exit `main`?

Comment: @EricStotch There's a huge difference in between raw memory and the objects that reside in. And per definition the destructor itself does not return any memory of the own object at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I understand now! It's actually a thread local variable in the main thread so there's no opportunities for it to `join()`. That's why I wanted to know if I can change where my pool is init/cleanup. Unless thread_local variables (declared in the same file as main) are guaranteed to run first/cleanup last I have 0 idea how to fix this outside of making main call another thread immediately and not use the thread local vars itself. For now I have a thread local int var that says if I ran cleanup already and simply return at the start of my pool functions

Comment: @EricStotch I don't think it would be too hard to fix it properly but it's hard to piece everything together from these descriptions. Perhaps if you open a new question and put a [mre] in it will you get an answer that doesn't require hacks. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I get into the answer, anyone reading this should know that this is generally a very bad idea, and should be treated as a last resort. However, what the OP wants is feasible, so here it is:

Destructors are possibly the single most reliable thing in the C++ language. So if you want to prevent one from being executed, you'll have to manage the object's lifecycle and memory by yourself.

We could just `new` the `Dummy` object and never `delete` it, but that would leak heap memory, which is not desirable. Instead, we want to create, but never destroy, the `Dummy` object in the memory associated with the thread-local object itself.

For this, the way to go is `std::aligned_storage` and `placement new`:

```cpp
struct Dummy { ~Dummy() { assert(0); } };

struct DummyWrapper {
  DummyWrapper() {
    // Create the dummy
    dummy_ptr = new (&dummy_data) Dummy();
  }

  // Intentionally leave the destructor defaulted-out
  ~DummyWrapper() = default;

  operator Dummy&() { return *dummy_ptr; }

  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Dummy), alignof(Dummy)> dummy_data;
  Dummy* dummy_ptr;
};

__thread DummyWrapper dumb;
```

The `DummyWrapper` object will be constructed and destroyed, there's no going around that. However, the `Dummy` object is only ever created, and never destroyed, but the underlying memory management is still kept sane.

Comment: This is a good answer. I think for my specific case I'll probably have another thread local var and mark the pool as dead so it just returns immediately. I was really hoping I could mark the one variable as never destruct :/

Comment: @EricStotch That's kind of a good thing. So much of C++ is scaffolded on destructors being reliable that if bypassing them was simple, all hell would break loose.

Comment: Yeah! Turns out I was still half stupid. I deleted a line that manually called the destructor and my cleanup code detected I didn't unmap some memory. I ended up implementing a `early_cleanup()` so I won't confuse myself or anyone else by manually calling a destructor that will execute again. It looks like things are sane again despite me not being able to request when my poll cleanup is executed

Comment: IDK if you happen to know but is it guaranteed that thread locals at the top of the file where main is located will run first? If so I'll be able to have my pool run first/last and will be able to delete some code

Comment: @EricStotch That's a separate question that deserves being asked by itself.

Comment: FML. I was right when I wrote this question. `__thread` doesn't actually let you have destructors I forgot I had my DEBUG_NO_LOCAL_THREAD macro on. Not a single person called me out on that mistake :/ I guess I'm using this solution after all